# Is it possible to use SQL profiler 2005 to profile a 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to trace a SQL Server 2008 database, but I only have SQL Profiler 2005 available to me.  (Don't ask why, it doesn't make sense to me either).   When I try to start a new trace, I get "Unable to locate trace definition file for Microsoft SQL Server version 10.0.0.  Click OK to retrieve it from the server.  Retrieval may take a few moments".

I click Ok, then ...  nothing.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 6):

You have to copy files from a SQL Server 2008 installation into the SQL Server 2005 installation. Copy "Microsoft SQL Server TraceDefinition 10.0.0.xml" (and "Microsoft SQL Server TraceDefinition 10.50.0.xml") from "C:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\TraceDefinitions" into "C:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Profiler\TraceDefinitions".

To be able to save templates, you have to create a new folder in "C:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Profiler\Templates". For SQL Server 2008 add a directory named "100", for SQL Server 2008R2 add a directory named "1050". If you don't have access to an SQL Server 2008 Profiler installation, you can copy the existing templates for SQL Server 2005 from "C:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Profiler\Templates\90" - they work with SQL Server 2008 too.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me no probs, happily profiling SQL 2008 R2 from SQL 2005 profiler. So ignore "it's not gonna work" answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible, provided you can get the SQL2008 trace definitions, the ones that install with SQL2005 are located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Profiler\TraceDefinitions

If you can get the SQL2008 versions (they are XML files) you should be good to go, hope this helps!